# Integer to Binary Conversion in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I know its a very basic question. But still, I am struggling to convert Binary to Integer and vice-versa in Simulink.

I could use a function block and use inbuilt Matlab functions to do it. But I, intend to use the Simulink blocks to convert Binary to decimal number.

Please suggest me how to do it or any pointers in the internet would be helpful.

Comment: What's your goal ? Value are in decimal base into Simulink but you have block such as `Extract bit` to use bits. Generally, you better have to think about bits than base within Simulnk. Let the visual representation outside in Matlab (or in `Display` blocs set to "binary")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [**Conversion block**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/datatypeconversion.html) to convert back and forth between binary (i.e. `boolean`) types and various integer (`int8`, `uint8`, `int16`, etc.) or floating point (`single` or `double`) types.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:

[How do I visualize the fixed-point data in binary or hex format using Simulink?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1AQON/index.html?product=FP&solution=1-1AQON)